# Time ago PHP with Current timestamp

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, pdo

I am French and this text comes from an online translator. I apologize in advance for misspellings.

Context: I'm trying to display in a page, the time difference between the creation of my article and the date of the day. Make a system similar to facebook, for comments posted.

Example "1 day ago".

Problem: When I apply my function on my article, it always shows me "just now" even several minutes later. I can dig my head but I do not understand it. Can you guide me to a track?

Here are the elements that can help you.

My method in my  article class:

```
enter code here  public function getDate_creation() {
    return $this->date_creation;
}

public function articleTimeAgo()
{
    $time_ago = strtotime($this->getDate_creation());
    $current_time = time();
    $time_difference = $current_time - $time_ago;
    $seconds = $time_difference;
    $minutes      = round($seconds / 60 );           // value 60 is seconds
    $hours           = round($seconds / 3600);           //value 3600 is 60 minutes * 60 sec
    $days          = round($seconds / 86400);          //86400 = 24 * 60 * 60;
    $weeks          = round($seconds / 604800);          // 7*24*60*60;
    $months          = round($seconds / 2629440);     //((365+365+365+365+366)/5/12)*24*60*60
    $years          = round($seconds / 31553280);     //(365+365+365+365+366)/5 * 24 * 60 * 60
    if($seconds <= 60)
    {
        return "Just Now";
    }
    else if($minutes <=60)
    {
        if($minutes==1)
        {
            return "one minute ago";
        }
        else
        {
            return "$minutes minutes ago";
        }
    }
    else if($hours <=24)
    {
        if($hours==1)
        {
            return "an hour ago";
        }
        else
        {
            return "$hours hrs ago";
        }
    }
    else if($days <= 7)
    {
        if($days==1)
        {
            return "yesterday";
        }
        else
        {
            return "$days days ago";
        }
    }
    else if($weeks <= 4.3) //4.3 == 52/12
    {
        if($weeks==1)
        {
            return "a week ago";
        }
        else
        {
            return "$weeks weeks ago";
        }
    }
    else if($months <=12)
    {
        if($months==1)
        {
            return "a month ago";
        }
        else
        {
            return "$months months ago";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($years==1)
        {
            return "one year ago";
        }
        else
        {
            return "$years years ago";
        }
    }
}
```

My view :

```
       <?php if (sizeof($articles) > 0) :
                    foreach ($articles as $article) : ?>
                        <div class="children">
                            <h3><?php echo (empty($article->getAuteur()) ? 'Anonyme' : $article->getAuteur()) ; ?></h3>
                            <p><?php echo $article->getDescription(); ?></p>
                            <span><p><?php echo $article->articleTimeAgo(); ?></p></span>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach;
                endif; ?>
```

I have doubts about the format of my fields in database, so I give you the format of the fields "date_creation":

type = timestamp
value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

I hope I have been clear enough. I remain at your disposal for any other information.

Comment: What does $seconds give you as value after calculating $seconds?

Comment: Check if your database is set to "current timestamp on update".

Comment: mysql: With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, the column has the current timestamp for its default value and is automatically updated to the current timestamp. Your 'date_creation' should not get updated.

Comment: I create my article in 2018-06-10 20:14:02.
At the moment he posted me article posted there are 7 minutes. Yet he is 22:24 at home. I do not understand. When I do a var_dump ($ seconds) it shows me 424.
When I create a new article, $ seconds is -7196. I think there is a gap.

Comment: Try to set your timezone via https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_default_timezone_set.asp

Comment: WAaouuu it's working thank you bro!!!!